# How to Join a table with a list NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have a list of objects like this

```
public  class MyList
    {
    
        public int recordNo { get; set; }

        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    }

var result= (from pool in context.Table.Where(prdicate)
                                             select new ResultEntity
                                             {
                                                 guid = pool.guid,
                                                 isValid = myList.FirstOrDefault(no => no.guid == pool.guid).IsValid //It thorws an error here
                                             }
```

the error is
**System.NotSupportedException:**
the error caused because IsValid assign

So I want to join the list with a table, to asssign some values on it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer customerAlias = null;
Organization organizationAlias = null;

IList<Customer> customers = session.QueryOver(() => customerAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Organization, () => organizationAlias)
    .Where(customer => customer.Name == "Customer Name")
    .And(() => customerAlias.Age > 18)
    .AndNot(() => organizationAlias.Name == "Forbidden Organization")
    .List();
```